# How can I access the fields of the Runnable object within my Thread

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, operating-system, java-threads

I am trying to get the time it takes the CPU to perform a context switch so I have a class taking the System time in nanoseconds and I put it into some threads but I need to get those numbers and perform computations on it but I don't know how I can access it.

This is my main function.

```
 public class GroupNinePipe{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Thread t1 = new Thread(new OSProj2("Thread1"));
        Thread t2 = new Thread(new OSProj2("Thread2"));
        Thread t3 = new Thread(new OSProj2("Thread3"));
        Thread t4 = new Thread(new OSProj2("Thread4"));
        Thread t5 = new Thread(new OSProj2("Thread5"));
        Thread t6 = new Thread(new OSProj2("Thread6"));

        OSProj2 n = new OSProj2("Thread 8");



        t1.start();
        t2.start();
        t3.start();
        t4.start();
        t5.start();
        t6.start();

    }
}
```

Class taking system time.

```
    public class OSProj2 implements Runnable {
    String name;
    long time;

    public OSProj2(String x)
    {
        name = x;


    }

    public void run()
    {
        try{
            time = System.nanoTime();
            System.out.printf("%s sys time: %d\n", name, time);
            this.getTime();


        }
        catch (Exception e){}
    }

    public long getTime()
    {
        return time;
    }
}
```

I know the name of the class says Pipe but I don't use one.

Answer (score 1):

I dont know if this is the right way to go about it but nevertheless, your code becomes like this

```
    Runnable osProj2 = new OSProj2("Thread1");
    Thread t1 = new Thread(osProj2);
    t1.start();

    try {
        t1.join();
     } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
     }
     System.out.println(osProj2.getTime()); // for example
```

The t1.join() will block until your thread finish running, hope i helped